# How can automatically verify if text is contained in an element on a web page?

Tags: python, selenium, responsive-design, automation

I am trying to create an automation suite using selenium to validate a responsive web design for different screen resolutions and sizes.

One of the key checkpoint is to verify if text of any element is confined to the it and does not spill outside when resolution changes.

I am currently using selenium to validate other scenarios.

Are there any functionalities in selenium that can be used to validate the above mentioned scenario.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think you should use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) instead of Selenium.

Comment: Simplest is `for i in driver_find_elements_by_xpath('//*'): assert not i.text == "text`"

Comment: [GalenFramework](http://galenframework.com/) may be the thing for you.It's a wrapper on top of Selenium

Comment: Hi @Andersson, This would help me find if text is matching but the problem is we would not know if text is enclosed in an element when a user views it

Comment: agreed with others, straight up Selenium is specifically designed so that you can write tests independent of screen resolution.  You'll need another tool like Sikuli or GalenFramework for what you want